# In Mirai no Mirai, where is the protagonist's family house in Japan?

Tags: mirai-no-mirai

[image]

Does anyone know where this location might be in Japan? Or is this a purely fictional location? I'm particularly interested in their house designs. The protagonist's neighbors' houses seem to be elevated. Is there a name for that style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an [interview](https://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2018/10/mamoru-hosoda-on-mirai-fatherhood-and-the-meaning.html) with Mamoru Hosoda, the film's director:

> Mirai is not set in Toyoma but rather in **Yokohama**, which is a port city that was one of the first cities to be modernized because of its contact with the West. I chose Yokohama, a city that is constantly changing, because Mirai is a story about how a family can change but always remains itself.

So, no this location is not fictional.

Regarding the house design or style, as @AkiTanaka mentioned, [these are called stepped houses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_(film)). The link also mentions that the house is located in **Kanazawa-ku, Yokohama**.

Answer (score 2):

The shown image is located around 35°22'25"N 139°37'24"E ([Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/35%C2%B022%2725.0%22N+139%C2%B037%2724.0%22E/@35.3738702,139.6233601,238m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d35.3736111!4d139.6233333)) which is in [Kanazawa-ku, Yokohama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanazawa-ku,_Yokohama).

[image]